# Incorrect sum when adding up numbers

Tags: c++, function, if-statement

Ok, here's the code to add indefinite numbers and present the sum in c++. But error is that addition taking place is of first number and the last digits of all the other numbers. For example if i want to add `30 + 40 + 55 + 70`, my program counts `30 + 0 + 0 + 5 + 0 = 35`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    cout << "Please enter numbers you want to add and end with N or n: ";

    for (;;)
    {
        cin >> num;
        sum += num;
        cout << endl;

        char indicator ('q');

        cin >> indicator;
        if (( indicator == 'n') || (indicator == 'N'))
            break;

    }
    cout << "The sum is: " << sum << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: u said addition took place between first and last number, in that case, shouldn't the output be 30+70 = 100???

Comment: Add `cin.putback(indicator);` at the end of your for loop.

Comment: Or replace `cin >> indicator;` with `indicator = cin.peek();`.

Comment: @someone_smiley OP meant "digit", not "number"; I edited to clarify

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to add a list of integers terminated by an `N` (or `n`) character, then you should read each entity as a string, see if it's the terminating character, and if it's not, then convert it to an integer:

```
int sum = 0;

while (true) {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    if (tolower(s[0]) == 'n')
        break;

    sum += std::stoi(s);
}
```

Of course, the above code is only a skeleton -- in production code, you should always check if I/O operations succeeded and sanitize your input. A more complete example would be:

```
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s) {
    int ch = s[0];

    if (ch > 0 && tolower(ch) == 'n')
        break;

    try {
        sum += std::stoi(s);
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument &e) {
        // handle conversion error
        break;
    } catch (const std::out_of_range &e) {
        // handle out-of-range error
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra work, and you still have undefined behavior (and possibly an endless loop).  Any solution which uses input without testing whether it has succeeded is _wrong_.

Comment: @JamesKanze I realize -- but the error checking is only omitted for clarity. Not sure whether the "extra work" would actually matter.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't mind undefined behavior or endless loops in your code.  The "standard" idiom (`while ( std::cin >> num )` avoids the issue (and also avoids all of the obfuscating `break`).

Comment: To be very clear: in my own answer, I add a lot of additional information about how to handle the `'n'`, because it shows additional useful idioms, but for what he's doing, which is obviously trying to learn C++, the _only_ thing he should really consider is `while ( std::cin >> num )` (which also avoids the necessity of special handling for the first element).

Comment: @JamesKanze "It doesn't matter if you don't mind undefined behavior or endless loops in your code." - nobody told you I don't mind undefined behavior or infinite loops. I do. I changed the `break` to `while (std::cin >> s)` because it's indeed more readable, but I still don't understand from where you are getting the idea that I don't care about UB. (I even added an amended code snippet when you pointed out that the naive approach is flawed. If anything, that should indicate to you that I do care about correctness.)

Comment: Your first snippet still has undefined behavior.  The second is more idiomatic (although the test for `s.size()` is unnecessary; if `std::cin >> s` succeeds, then `s` is guaranteed not to be empty).  (And of course, `tolower(s[0])` is undefined behavior on most systems.)  And I'd consider calling `std::stoi` without a surrounding try block an error as well; the fact that the function reports errors by throwing makes it fairly difficult to use correctly in a lot of circumstances.

Comment: @JamesKanze Added exception handling. -- "And of course, `tolower(s[0])` is undefined behavior on most systems." - why so? The only piece of undefined behavior I could find in connection with `tolower` is when it is called with a negative value other than EOF. If the input only consists of spaces, digits and the letters `n` and `N`, then that is not the case, is it?

Comment: Why is `tolower( s[0] )` undefined behavior?  Because the standard says so: the input to `tolower` is an `int`, and must be in the range `[0, UCHAR_MAX]` (or be `EOF`).  On most systems, this constraint won't be met when converting a `char` to `int`.

Comment: @JamesKanze so it is undefined even if the **actual** values passed to it (at runtime) are **never** negative? just because they have the potential to ever be negative?

Comment: @JamesKanze Okay, apart from the snark -- what if they are not? Nowadays, it's fairly common to use ASCII or a superset thereof. (I don't know of a reasonably popular consumer OS/C++ stdlib implementation which uses anything else.) These encodings have values for space, digits and English (non-accented) characters which fit into an 8-bit (i. e. minimal) `char`, even into a signed one. So, as long as the input is in the promised format, there's no reason to think that there will be negative `char`s. But okay, added a check for negative numbers anyway. I hope my code now satisfies you.

Answer (score 3):

When you read the indicator, you extract the next non-blank character from the input stream; if the user has entered a number, this is the first digit.  There are several ways of working around this.

The simplest is simply to loop on:

```
while ( std::cin >> num ) {
    sum += num;
}
```

The input will fail if the next input doesn't have the form of a number (without extracting it).  (This also has the advantage that you don't use the input if it fails for some reason.)  This is more or less the standard idiom.

If you really do want to check for the `'n'`, you can use `std::cin.peek()` to look ahead one character, without extracting it.  This doesn't skip white space, however, so you might want to do `std::cin >> std::ws` first.  In this case, you'd probably want to wrap it in a function:

```
bool
terminationRequested( std::istream& source )
{
    source >> std::ws;
    return source.peek() == 'n' || source.peek() == 'N';
}
```

and then

```
while ( ! terminationRequested( std::cin ) ) {
    int num;
    std::cin >> num;
    if ( ! std::cin ) {
        //  error...
    }
    sum += num;
}
```

You still have to check for a possible error after `std::cin >> num`.  Otherwise, if the user enters `"a"`, you'll end up in an endless loop, adding an undefined value to `sum`.

Alternatively, another frequent idiom is too use putback to return the indicator to the stream:

```
while ( std::cin >> indicator && indicator != 'n' && indicator != 'N' ) {
    std::cin.putback( indicator );
    std::cin >> num;
    if ( ! std::cin ) {
        //  error...
    }
    sum += num;
}
```

Again, you'll have to handle the errors somehow.  Using `num` if `std::cin >> num` fails is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you read the indicator character which will remove and ignore the next input digit by the user from the input stream.